# Access Denied while creating crawler

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

**Trying to create a crawler to create a table in the data catalog**

> One crawler failed to create The following crawler failed to create:
> "annual_reports_crawl" Here is the most recent error message: Account
> xxxxxx is denied access.

I have given **AmazonS3FullAccess** and **AWSGlueServiceRole** access to the IAM.

Can someone help?

Comment: Is the S3 bucket in the same AWS Account as the Glue crawler you are running?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes.